# Can't a list have symbols in it?

Tags: python

I have not done python before (only javascript). I am finding the docs alien and the other stackoverflow posts on `list.pop()` even more cryptic!

my args are `'0','0','0','0','0000'`

here's my code:

```
i=['.','.','.',':','']

host=''
for v in sys.argv[1:]:
    host=host+str(v)+str(i.pop())
host=host[:-1]

print host
```

I'm trying to get `'0.0.0.0:0000'`

But instead I get: `IndexError: pop from empty list`

https://repl.it/DirH/1

The reason I ask is that I can't find any SO questions where the list is symbols **and** the list is declared in plain writing!

Comment: You know `pop()` pulls from the end, not the beginning, right? If you want the beginning, try `pop(0)`.

Comment: *"where the list is symbols and the list is declared in plain writing!"* - what? Those are most single character strings, and I think you're trying to describe a list literal. This is **no different** to a JS array literal.

Comment: yeah pop pulls from the end (was going to fix that later once I figure out what shifts from the start)

Comment: `pop` removes from the list, as the doc states. So once you have popped all the list, it is empty, and the call fails. It all boils down to whether or not your `argv[1:]` is longer than the list or not.

Comment: Why are you joining the arguments this way? What is your real goal, what are you really trying to do?

Comment: (also, what do you expect `[1:]` to do?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a=['script','location','00','11','22','33','4444']
i=['.','.','.',':','',''] # added an extra ''

host=''

for v in a[1:]:
    host=host+str(v)+i.pop(0)

print (host)
```

Something like this? Changed pop(0) cause you want the start not the end. Your issue was you were trying to pop more than there was.

Answer (score 4):

You *can* put pretty much whatever you want in a list.  It's likely that your `sys.argv` is too long (even after slicing off the first element).

e.g. if `len(sys.argv[1:]) == 6` and `len(i) == 5` than by the time you get to the last element in the `for` loop, `i` will be empty.  This appears to be the case from the code you posted in the link.

Also note that you're probably better off using `zip`:

```
lst = ['.','.','.',':','']
for v, ii in zip(sys.argv[1:], lst):  # possibly reversed(i) if you meant to pop off the left side of the list rather than the end?
    host += host + str(v)+ str(ii)
```

Or (more efficiently):

```
host = ''.join(j+ii for j, ii in zip(sys.argv[1:], lst))
```

Of course, you still likely end up with incorrect output (even with `zip`) if the input lists aren't the correct lengths -- However, you won't get an exception, just a shorter output string than you might be expecting since `zip` truncates when one of the iterables is exhausted.

Comment: Or `host = ''.join(i+j for i, j in zip(sys.argv[1:], lst))`

Comment: @Mr.goosberry -- No.  Unfortunately, the name that OP is using for the list is `i`.  Maybe I should just change _all_ the names for the sake of clarity ...

Comment: @MosesKoledoye -- I was trying to go slow and not introduce _too_ much at once.  With that said, it's pretty hard form me to leave an answer where I use `+=` to build a string so I've added the `''.join` version as well...

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you want is simple: join everything using the dot, but the last part, the port number must be joined by colon. Here is another way to do it:

```
port = sys.argv.pop()
host = '{}:{}'.format('.'.join(sys.argv[1:]), port)
```